# Certain keys Don't Work on Laptop Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a several year old laptop.  As of a couple days ago, certain keys won't work ("m" is one of those that don't work).  However....

1. If I hold shift, I will get "M", or sometimes "MM" (from one pressing of the "m" key).
2. If I quickly alternate between pressing/not pressing shift while pressing the "m" key repeatedly, I'll sometimes get a lowercase "m".
3. Using a USB keyboard works fine.

My laptop is a MSI A5000.

Any thoughts on how I might fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more info about the type of laptop you have.  You may need to replace it and we may be able to give you steps to do it if the make and model are known.

Comment: Sounds like a (partially) stuck key. Have you tried removing the key cap and cleaning underneath? Cleaning the keyboard with compressed air? It could just be a small crumb underneath the key cap.

Comment: When I was younger and had more time on my hands, I took apart my keyboard (that went thru a small water spill and had a few flaky or not working keys) and found bad spots on the plastic sheet for the corresponding keys' circuit traces and taped small pieces of aluminum foil over the bad spots, and it worked... for several months. I redid it once more and it worked for a few months more. Then I got a new keyboard, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try reinstalling the drivers first.  [MSI website](http://us.msi.com/search/)

If that doesn't work, changing a keyboard is usually pretty straightforward.

Just google your keyboard type and order one from wherever you like to order things online.  Then check out [This tutorial](http://www.laptopkeyboard.com/Guides.php/MSI/A%20Series/A5000-436US/KBMS5) and you should be all set.

All you need to do is remove a few screws from the back (bottom) of the laptop -- making sure to note their locations -- and carefully remove the old keyboard.  Usually there are a few retractable tabs holding the keyboard down.  I use a small flathead screwdriver to get at the tabs.  Then unplug the connection from the motherboard and put the new one in.

Good luck.

Comment: Here's one possible place to order from.  http://www.amazon.com/replacement-keyboard-MSI-MP-03233U4-359D-S1N-3UUS141-C54/dp/B00H8KQD10

Answer (score 0):

Consider purchasing a new laptop keyboard online.  They usually are inexpensive and simple to replace (sometimes zero screws).  If your vendor doesn't provide a service guide, YouTube has videos to help.